# Header with 2 cells aligned in the same row, itextpdf 5.5.10

Tags: itext

I have a row in my header, which looks good, but I need to add another String in the same row, so it is on the right side of it

When I try to add that String in the same cell, everything loses the alignment

```
private void addHeader(PdfWriter writer) {
    PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(2);
    try {
        // set defaults
        header.setWidths(new int[] { 20, 12, 12 });
        header.setTotalWidth(527);
        header.setLockedWidth(true);
        header.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(5);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        header.getDefaultCell().setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        // add text
        PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell();
        text.setPaddingBottom(12);
        text.setPaddingLeft(8);
        text.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        text.setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        text.addElement(new Phrase("Hi", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD)));
        text.addElement(new Phrase("", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8)));
        text.addElement(new Phrase("Hi" + "CVE-2017-2018", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9)));
        header.addCell(text);
        // add image
        Image logo = Image.getInstance(App.class.getResource(LOGO_2));
        header.addCell(logo);

        PdfPCell cveTitle = new PdfPCell();
        cveTitle.setPaddingBottom(15);
        cveTitle.setPaddingLeft(8);
        cveTitle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
        cveTitle.setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
        cveTitle.addElement(new Phrase("3 Cell", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD)));
        header.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        header.addCell(cveTitle);

}
```

**CVE-2010-2016** 
Is just what I want to do, leave it on the right side

**Update**

The solution was to add a new value to the array, corresponding to a new cell, and also instantiating PdfPCell again, thks

Comment: Where in your code do you *try to add that String in the same cell*?

Comment: Sorry for explaining me wrong, say, 2 cells in the same row.

Comment: Well, you already have two cells, one for the logo and one for the text. You could add a third cell to the same row if you changed the number of columns in the `PdfPTable` constructor and considered the additional column in the `setWidths` call...

Comment: Of course, thank you very much, the solution was that, with the contructor tableHeader.setWidths(new int[] { 20, 12, 12 });

Answer (score 0):

Just from the classname PdfPTable, I can tell the iText version you are using is pretty outdated.

Please consider switching to a newer version. Latest version is iText7.

Comment: Also, providing us with your .pdf document will help in getting the problem solved.

Comment: Not being negative, but according to the question title, the _latest_ version of iText (5.5.10 released 2016-10) is being used. Not to mention that iText 5 is actively maintained - there was a commit on Github only yesterday. To be honest, though, I've been unable to find how long the development team will continue to maintain that branch.

Comment: Well, put the version after the comment of Joris Schellekens

Comment: @kuujinbo End-Of-Life information is right here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/itext/3557/getting-started-with-itext#t=201703151411361159498&a=versions :)

Comment: My apologies. I only took a glance at the code.
I would still recommend you switch to iText7.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - thank you. I only looked at GiHub and the iText web site.

Comment: @kuujinbo That information should also be somewhere on the iText website, I'll ask around.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is colspan and rowspan.
Have a look at the tutorial:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-colspan-and-rowspan